# python3 detect non-english for unicode?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

In python3, is there a way to find if a given UTF code contain any non-english character? The provided is a byte code and I use the below line to convert it to UTF.

```
line = line.decode("UTF-8")
```

After converting, I would like to detect if this line contains any non-english (non ascii) characters.

Comment: Plenty of non-ASCII characters are valid for use in English, and several non-English languages use ASCII, more if you include transliterations.

Comment: ^ Yes. I think the best example is any English text from a word processor or something similar will contain slanted quotes/apostrophes generated by a "smart quotes" feature, and those are non-ASCII.

Comment: Not to mention words such as "naïve" and "résumé".

Answer (score 2):

Yup:

```
^[ -~]+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vG1eN0/2).
For an explanation (with a table that is), have a look [at this blog post](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/my-favorite-regex/).